# How to scroll to tag with mouse wheel

Tags: jquery, mousewheel, smooth-scrolling

i'm looking to find the method used in the website attached in this post to scroll between sections of the page with just one movement of mouse wheel.
I think the question is a bit confusing, but you have just to visit the website and then use the mouse wheel to understand what i mean.
Is it a jQuery function?

http://atieva.com/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a built in JQuery function. However there are many plugins out there.
Some examples that showed up:

http://projects.lukehaas.me/scrollify/

http://alvarotrigo.com/multiScroll/

and so on if your search for terms like Jquery scroll section

Comment: Thank you! That's what i was searching

Comment: Glad it helped you :)